# Android sockets: listening doesn't work through 4G

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp

I'm learning Android and Java programming on my own. To practise, I've developed a couple of apps, and now I'm trying to write a chat-like application. So basically, I want to to something like WhatsApp. I have a server program also coded by me running in my computer, and it's what the chat in the Android system uses to communicate. So basically, everything is sent to the server and the server does what required to deliver the messages.
So here is what I have:

1. First, my app sends a "Hello" to my server (known IP and port)
2. The server stores the IP and the port (also the username) used by each user
3. When the server is asked to deliver a message to a user, it sends it to the IP and port stored

I use a socket for the "Hello", but I can't use the same one for sending back messages (because of how I programmed the server). But this is not the problem. When the server receives the "Hello", it's listening on the corresponding port. But when the server is the one who has to start the connection, it's the app the one who has to. In order to do this, the app must know on what port it must listen (it doesn't know because of NAT), and I tell it so sending back the port used through the first socket used for the "Hello" message. Despite this, my app is unable to receive messages and stays in the receive call.
Here you have the code:
Server:

```
    DatagramSocket client = new DatagramSocket(2048); //Predefined port
    DatagramPacket receivePacket;
    byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
    receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
            receiveData.length);
    System.out.println("Ready to receive");
    client.receive(receivePacket);
    System.out.println("Received successfuly");
    String receivedPort = String.valueOf(receivePacket.getPort());
    byte[] sendData = receivedPort.getBytes();
    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, receivePacket.getAddress(), receivePacket.getPort());
    client.send(sendPacket); //Send back the port used by the app
    System.out.println("Sent successfuly");
    client.close();
    Thread.sleep(1000); //To make sure the app is ready to listen
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
    byte[] sendData2 = "Working like a charm".getBytes();
    InetAddress ip = receivePacket.getAddress();
    int port = receivePacket.getPort();
    System.out.println(ip + " " + port);
    DatagramPacket sendPacket2 = new DatagramPacket(sendData2, sendData2.length, ip, port);
    socket.send(sendPacket);
    System.out.println("Sent successfuly 2nd time");
    socket.close();
```

Client (Android app):

```
EditText eT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.messageText);
String message = eT.getText().toString();
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
byte[] sendData = message.getBytes();
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName(MY_COMPUTER'S_IP);
DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, ip, 2048);
socket.send(sendPacket);
byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
socket.receive(receivePacket); //Receive the port used (and that must be opened and redirecting the traffic to this device due to NAT)
socket.close();
String receivedMessage = new String(receivePacket.getData());
String receivedData = new String(receivePacket.getData());
String actualData = receivedData.substring(0, receivePacket.getLength());
Log.d("Port", actualData);
int port = Integer.parseInt(actualData);
DatagramSocket socket2 = new DatagramSocket(port);
DatagramPacket receivePacket2;
byte[] receiveData2 = new byte[1024];
receivePacket2 = new DatagramPacket(receiveData2,
        receiveData2.length);
socket2.receive(receivePacket2); //Here is where it gets blocked
String data = new String(receivePacket2.getData());
Log.d("Finally received", data.substring(receivePacket2.getLength()));
socket2.close();
```

Does anybody know why my messages aren't making it back through the second socket? I've checked and the IP and ports are correct.
Thanks in advance for answering, and I apologize for my formatting.

Comment: Maybe a firewall is blocking the communication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many mobile phone companies currently assign a private IP to 3G-4G connected devices.

It is as if the devices were inside a LAN. You do not have access to the gateway router of this LAN and without a NAT the listening ports of your device are inaccessible from outside.

To know if your IP is public or private compare the IP of the device with the one sites like showmyip.com say, if they are different your device is in your phone company LAN.

To obtain the device IP some application like PingTools can help.

Comment: Yes, the IP of my device is private. What I do is to listen on the port assigned by the tower (which acts like a router), so if a datagram is sent to the tower's IP (the public of my device) and on the port where it came from, it should get to my device, right? The tower sees someone is replying to that device because it knows that the port corresponds to that device. Unless the close() call closes the port...

Comment: No, as i said your listening device ports are inaccessible from outside. Same thing if you connect via Wi.FI and you don't create a NAT rule in the router.

Comment: And that assumption of yours that the company's router redirects the packets back to your port is 100% wrong. That magic automatism does not exist. The only way the device with a 4G private IP can connect with the outside world is to connect via TCP to an external server then if a connection is established the external server can send packets to your Android device.

Comment: But I can't be wrong if the first part works. I mean, the device sends a datagram, and the machine who receives it can actually respond if it sends anotherone to the IP and port the first had. That's how we are able to access the Internet: the web is sent back to the port and IP that the GET request came from. That is this way because the tower who decided to use that port, knows that anything that is received in the port used to translate an address is for the device assigned to it. Am I saying anything wrong? Again, thank you for your answers.

Comment: That is true for a connected socket like TCP because there are a previous negotiation and a connection before any data is sent. But it's not true for non connected sockets like UDP (Datagram).

Comment: Mmm... perhaps it's this. Will give TCP a go and then I'll tell you how it went!

Comment: But always the 4G device must be the client, as server the listening port will be also inaccessible.

Comment: So the problem is that the app can't listen on that port? Okey, thank you so much, will try with a different approach.

Comment: The app can listen but all device ports are inaccessible from the WAN. therefore the device can not act server, neither in TCP nor in UDP.

Answer (score 0):

First tell me is the device connected to the direct ip address or the subnet ? Is the device having some ip address like local ip 192.168 ..? and the is the NAT configured properly on the router to forward the packets to the respective port on the device ?

What i suspect is you device able to send because the server ip is going to be a static one. While receiving it might not reach the device... You tell me what is the ip address of the device and the server..

Once after ypu replied we can figure out the problem. In android its better if you use the websockets and send and receive the messages over wss connection. Also to reduce the power consumption try to use the google push notification service or the firebase messaging service to enable chat functionality.

Comment: First of all, thank you for answering. So yes, the IP of my server is static, as it has to be. The device one is not, I'm trying to do it thorugh 4G. So I know that when a datagram is sent, the antenna acts like a router and adds the port to the port list so if something is received back to that port it is redirected back to the device. I suppose that if I know what was that port (that the antenna chose) and I listen on it, I can receive messages sent to my public IP (which is the antenna's IP) and the specified port. Is that right?

Comment: Why not you give a try to create a socket connection with the server at the client on the particular port rather than device creating the dynamic port ..? So you can be pretty sure about the port right..